# Where am I going wrong when creating authentication in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

**PHP 7.4**

**Laravel 8**

**Route 1** (super.com/auth):
Receives email, password data and makes authentication.

```
$result = Auth::Attempt(['password' => 'superpwd', 'email' => 'super@mail.ru'], true);
Auth::check() // true
```

**Route 2** (super.com/testAuthCheck):
We check the authentication.

```
Auth::check(); // false
```

It turns out that the authentication is not saved in the session.
Please tell me where I'm wrong? May be session or some setting, or modules...

**Full code**:

```
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Hash;

class AuthUser extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name'       => 'required|string',
            'lastname'   => 'required|string',
            'secondname' => 'required|string',
            'tel'        => 'required|numeric',
            'password'   => 'required|string',
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name'       => $request->name,
            'lastname'   => $request->lastname,
            'secondname' => $request->secondname,
            'tel'        => $request->tel,
            'password'   => Hash::make($request->password),
            'email'      => '',
        ]);

        $login = Auth::login($user);

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Success!',
            'login' => $login
        ]);
    }
    public function test(Request $request) {
        if(Auth::Attempt(['password' => 111, 'email' => 'a@b.ru'], true)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            $result = Auth::check();
            dump($result); // true
        }
    }

    public function test2(Request $request) {
        $result = Auth::check();
        dump($result); // false
    }
```

Comment: what middleware are you using on these routes? Kindly show routes and kernal

Comment: Without middleware: Route::get('/test', [AuthUser::class, 'test'])->name('test');
Route::get('/test2', [AuthUser::class, 'test2'])->name('test2');

Answer (score 0):

Using `dump` will most likely cause more problems while debugging this.

```php
     public function test(Request $request) {
        if(Auth::Attempt(['password' => 111, 'email' => 'a@b.ru'], true)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            $result = Auth::check();
            //dump($result); ***will terminate the request and the session will not be set correctly ***
            info($result); // check storage/logs/laravel.log

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. "[2021-02-11 23:34:00] local.INFO: 1" But there no effect.